# Print all items from database Mongoose using Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose

UPDATED

I want to print all the items from the database reizen (in Mongoose) that I created. It never prints the items it always prints immediatly prints 'Geen reizen'. I've been looking for quite some time and I don't know how to fix it. My code is:

```
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

/* GET reizen*/
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.cookies.username != '') {
    res.render('reizen', { sisu : req.cookies.username });
  }
  else {
    res.render('reizen', { sisu : 'SIGN IN/SIGN UP'});
  }
});

router.get('/getreizen', function(req, res, next) {
  reizen.find({}, function(err, reizen) {
    res.render('reizen', {reizen: reizen});
  });
});
```

I'm still working on the first part, about the cookies, so you can ignore that part.

My code in pug is:

```
extends layout

block content
    #reizen.w3-content.w3-container.w3-padding-64
        h3.w3-center REIZEN
        a.w3-bar-item.border-button(href='/reistoevoegen') 
            |   VOEG REIS TOE
        p
            |
            |
        p
            each val in reizen
                a Titel: #{val.titel}
            else
                li Geen reizen.
```

I'm using `each val in reizen ? reizen: []` because otherwise I get the error 'can't get property length from undefined'.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature is wrong, you are using:

```
reizen.find({}, function(reizen) {
    res.render('reizen', {reizen: reizen});
  });
```

But the callback has the [signature](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) `function(err, reizen)`.

So you are trying to print the error (`err`) in your template which is undefined.

---

**Update:**

Next Test is to exclude the db from the equation. Update code and run again.

```
const data = [
   { titel: "A" },
   { titel: "B" },
]
res.render('reizen', {reizen: data});
```

Comment: So I changed `function(reizen)` to function `function(err, reizen)` and nothing changed. Are there still other mistakes? It's my first time working with Pug and I don't understand everything yet.

Comment: I updated the code, it's also my first time on stack overflow ;-)

Comment: Welcome then :D

Comment: Then you have to do some debugging. Enter the Line `console.log("reizen",reizen)` before the line `res.render('reizen', {reizen: reizen});`. What is the output when you run the program?

Comment: And next thing I would try is to remove `? reizen : []` from `each val in reizen ? reizen: []`.

Comment: There is nothing.. Just GET /reizen 304 97.929 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 0.651 ms - -
GET /images/italie.jpg 304 0.443 ms - - 
But these are the normal things.
There are btw actually object in my database

Comment: If I remove `? reizen : []` than I get the error 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

Comment: Next Test is to exclude the db from the equation. Answer updated above

Comment: Still no difference and I will add updated to my question

Comment: Sooo with the new change my app crashed so I can't test it

Comment: pls update your code and run again https://codesandbox.io/s/black-rgb-7ggu7